# count down from a specific number from a number inputted in python

Tags: python

basically I want var2 to make the bottle drop by that number e.g. when I type in 10 then 2 I want the bottle to count down in 2s like 10 8 6 4 2 0

```
var = raw_input(" Enter bottle number ")
var2 = raw_input(" Enter how many bottle taken down ")

bottle_number = int(var)
bottle_down = int(var2)

countdown = ""                             

while bottle_number > 0:                      

    print bottle_number, "bottles of beer on the wall,", bottle_number, "bottles of beer."
    print "Take one down and pass it around,", bottle_number - 1, "bottles of beer on the wall."
    print " "
    countdown = bottle_number - 1
    bottle_number = countdown


if bottle_number == 0:                        

    print """
    No more bottles of beer on the wall, no more bottles of beer.
    """
```

Comment: @cdhowie: I'm not sure it matters. He explained the problem, he showed us what he tried (and it was obviously a solid effort), that makes it a good question.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is subtract `bottle_down` instead of `1`. That's it.

Of course you probably want to change the text as well, so it says `"Take", bottle_down, "down"` instead of `"Take one down"`, or the output is a little confusing.

Meanwhile…

There's no reason to do this:

```
countdown = bottle_number - bottle_down
bottle_number = countdown
```

Just do:

```
bottle_number = bottle_number - bottle_down
```

Or:

```
bottle_number -= bottle_down
```

And there's no reason to initialize `countdown = ""` at the top. You never use that value, so why store it?

Meanwhile, instead of calculating `bottle_number - bottle_down` twice (once in the `print` statement, and then again to store for the next loop), why not just do it once, before the `print` statement?

Finally, at the end, you've got:

```
if bottle_number == 0:
```

So, if you run it with `9` and `2`, because you eventually end up with -1 bottles instead of 0, this last verse doesn't get printed. Is that what you want? (Also, when you're down to 1, and take 2, it's going to print the verse "Take 2 down and pass it around, -1 bottles of beer on the wall." But that sounds like something that people—or at least chemically-enhanced math freshmen—might actually sing.)

Comment: if bottle_number <= 0: - for if you want it printed for all cases where there are none left